# MapServer - Adjust brightness and contrast of a layer

Tags: geotiff-tiff, mapserver, pixel

I'm completely new to GIS/MapServer stuff. I'm working on an application that displays geotiff images on a 3d earth/map. I'd like to be able to adjust the brightness and contrast for this imagery via a MapServer .map file.

Here is my .map file. It's important to note that the source geotiff image is a grayscale image that gets a palette applied to it.

```
MAP
  NAME "SDS-Mosaic-000-File-000"
  EXTENT -85.6879738230316 30.0753848228994 -85.6850673399472 30.079471996768
  IMAGETYPE png24
  STATUS ON
  UNITS DD
  CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "C:/MapServer/proj/"
  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "png24"
    MIMETYPE "image/png"
    DRIVER AGG/PNG
    EXTENSION "png"
    IMAGEMODE RGBA
    TRANSPARENT ON
    FORMATOPTION "PALETTE=C:\ProgramData\Palettes\bronze.pal"
    FORMATOPTION "PALETTE_FORCE=on"
  END
  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END
  WEB
    METADATA
        "distance_units" "MS_DD"
        "mapmanager_version" "1.1.0.0"
        "ows_enable_request" "*"
        "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
        "wms_title" "MosaicTile-000-File-000"
    END
  END
  LAYER
    NAME "mshdf-tif-2021-23-03-18-02-06"
    DATA "mshdf-tif-2021-23-03-18-02-06.tif"
    OFFSITE 255 255 255
    PROJECTION
        AUTO
    END
    METADATA
        "wms_title" "mshdf-tif-2021-23-03-18-02-06"
        "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
        "distance_units" "MS_DD"
    END
    TYPE RASTER
  END
END
```

I've experienced with the 'COMPOSITE' block and 'COMPFILTER' options in MapServer.

I've added this to my 'LAYER' section:

```
COMPOSITE 
    COMPFILTER "whiten()"
END
```

This resulted in my imagery being solid yellow. I've added 'OPACITY' to the COMPOSITE section and it changes to a different shade of yellow but still solid (i.e. the imagery can't be seen - just a solid color).

I've also added to the LAYER section:

```
CLASS
  STYLE
      COLOR 255 0 0
  END
END
```

just to see if it would change anything but the imagery remains the same.

Does anyone know how to adjust contrast and/or brightness via a .map file. Is it even possible?

Comment: I am not sure where in the rendering chain MapServer applies the filters, but if it happens before applying the color palette I guess the result could be really weird. Maybe you could test composite with a  normal RGB source and outputformat just out of curiosity.

Comment: I removed the palette (left with a grayscale image) and no change occurs  with my STYLE or COMPFILTER blocks.

Comment: Doesn't even OPACITY have any effect?

Comment: How are you generating the output images? Is it via map2img command line, through HTTP calls? Through OpenLayers? It would be good to add an example of an HTTP call to the question.